# SpringFramework: @Transactional(readOnly = true) not working with h2

Tags: spring, spring-data, h2, spring-transactions

I am doing transaction testing with the SpringFramework.
I have the following classes.

**UserService.class**

```
@Transactional
public interface UserService {
    void add(User user);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User get(String id);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<User> getAll();

    void deleteAll();

    void update(User user);
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.class**

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    // skip some methods
    @Override public void update(User user) { userDao.update(user); }
}
```

**TestUserService.class**

```
public class TestUserService extends UserServiceImpl {
    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        for (User user : super.getAll()) {
            // try to update in get* method. it's read-only. 
            super.update(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
@Test(expected = TransientDataAccessResourceException.class)
public void readOnlyTransactionAttribute() {
    testUserService.getAll();
}
```

This test code is a success case when using mysql. But it fails when using H2 In-memory database. This is because the transaction completes without an exception.

I read the Spring Framework documentation and found the following:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--

> This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction but rather silently ignore the hint.

But I wonder if there is a way to pass this test with the H2 database.

Comment: read-only is just a hint (as stated in the documentation). If you want to handle that in a db that doesn't do anything with that flag, you will need to modify the jdbc driver. Which is probably something you don't want to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you!