# Why do I have to use @Modifying with @Transactional in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Whenever implementing data modifying logic using `Query` annotation (`insert`, `update` or `delete`) in `JpaRepository`, both `@Transactional` (not necessarily on the repository method) and `@Modifying` have to be used.

My understanding is as follows. All crud operations provided by `JpaRepository` are transactional unless we overwrite them. When implementing a method in a repository, we need to make sure it's still transactional. It can be achieved simply by annotating with `@Transactional`. The default value of `readOnly` is `false`, hence spring "knows" it's a modifying query.

The question is: **why do we need `@Modifying` annotation then (together with `@Transactional`)?** Maybe I'm missing something?

I'm aware of the discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314475/do-we-need-both-transaction-and-modifying-annotation-in-spring) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665090/why-do-we-have-to-use-modifying-annotation-for-queries-in-data-jpa), but I'm missing an explicit explanation for why `@Modifying` has to be used if `@Transactional` carries all the information needed.

Answer (score 3):

From the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

> By default, CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional.
>   For read operations, the transaction configuration readOnly flag is
>   set to true. All others are configured with a plain @Transactional so
>   that default transaction configuration applies.

and [@Modifying](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html) answers the question **why do we need @Modifying annotation then?**

> Indicates a query method should be considered as modifying query as
>   that changes the way it needs to be executed. **This annotation is only
>   considered if used on query methods defined through a Query
>   annotation). It's not applied on custom implementation methods or
>   queries derived from the method name as they already have control over
>   the underlying data access APIs or specify if they are modifying by
>   their name.**
>
> Queries that require a `@Modifying` annotation include INSERT, UPDATE,
>   DELETE, and DDL statements.

[also](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

> The @Modifying annotation is only relevant in combination with the
>   @Query annotation. Derived query methods or custom methods do not
>   require this Annotation.

**(together with @Transactional)**

`@Transactional` is not required along with `@Modifying`. It is just that the method annotated with `@Modifying` should execute within a transaction.

Comment: _"@Transactional(readOnly=true) can call a repository method annotated with @Modifying"_ as far as I'm aware only on data sources that don't support read-only transactions, otherwise execution will fail.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I admit that I am not aware of that . I tested this on an in-memory h2 database. If the example is wrong I will edit that out

Comment: It looks like H2 doesn't have read-only transactions (eg see [SpringFramework: @Transactional(readOnly = true) not working with h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499137/springframework-transactionalreadonly-true-not-working-with-h2))

Comment: Thank you . I will modify the answer